# smart pointers and when they destruct the object they point to

Tags: c++

I wish to use a smart pointer to an object that will be accessed by quite a few different objects. Therefore i don't want to destruct it until all the pointers are released to it. The smart pointer will point to an object that instantiates a couple objects, which instantiate a couple objects, and so on, so that you can access all the individual System objects through this one pointer. However, let's say that i create the smart pointer in main as `std::shared_ptr<System> object(new System);` and then let's say i have another object that all other entities derive from which has a static std::shared_ptr that i set equal to object above. The static declaration means that it's managed by the compiler and not on a per instance basis. So let's say that all the objects that derive from the base class use this static pointer to access the System object. WHEN is this smart pointer destructed if ever? I need this pointer to be destructed before the one in main, who's destruction should drop the reference count to 0, destroying the object pointed to by it. So my question is, when is a statically declared std::shared_ptr destructed in the scheme of things. Or even if a pointer were declared globally and used all over, when would this object be destructed?

the base class would look something like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
    static shared_ptr<System> m_System;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<System> system(new System);
    Base::m_System = system;

    /*
        other stuff
    */ 
    return 0;
}
```

also another thing that someone could help me with, i'm not very good with const-ness, and i would like for that static pointer to be a constant that cannot be changed by the derived classes. But then if it's const i can't initialize it like i did in main, right? so how would i go about declaring it so that it is const, but i can still set it equal to a pointer initially like this.

Comment: `shared_ptr`s are not magical. They are just objects like any other. The rules are the same as for other objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 2 reference for object, so, when we exit from main function - we decrement reference counter and then destruction of static objects decrement reference counter, when reference counter will be equal to 0, our System object will be destroyed.

Comment: yeh, but which shared_ptr is destructed first? the one in main, or the static pointer in the base class.

Comment: @FatalCatharsis: The one in `main` is destroyed when `main` exits; statics are destroyed after `main` exits.

Answer (score 1):

> WHEN is this smart pointer destructed if ever?

Like all static objects, it's destroyed after `main` exits.

> I need this pointer to be destructed before the one in main, who's destruction should drop the reference count to 0, destroying the object pointed to by it.

In that case, perhaps you want the static pointer to be a `weak_ptr`. It won't participate in the reference-counting that keeps the object alive, but will allow access to the object as long as there is a shared pointer to it. Then the object will be destroyed once the the pointer in `main()` (and any other copies of that pointer) go out of scope.

Alternatively, it might be worth thinking about avoiding static objects, and instead instantiate the object within `main()` and pass references to whatever needs it. This avoids various problems associated with static objects (in particular, their initialisation order), and also makes the program's dependency structure clearer. In that case, you probably don't need a smart pointer at all, since the object lifetime is bound to that of the program.

Comment: i will not be able to instantiate the derived objects within the main, because they are not defined at compile time. within an object  that is declared within main, there is map that is indexed by strings, which relates to pointers to templated functions of the type you associate with the string. this function then returns a new instance of that object, pointed to by Base * . This way, i am able to read from a file, a string related to the type and it's data, and create them dynamically. because of this, it's very hard to give each of them a reference. So i needed a solution like this :\

Comment: OK, in that case you could `new` it in main, manage it with `unique_ptr`, and pass references to whatever needs it; still no need for a global.

Comment: whoa time out, you can pass references from a unique_ptr? how does that work?

Comment: @FatalCatharsis: `void f(T&); std::unique_ptr<T> p(new T); f(*p);`

Comment: HA, reference parameters. when you said references i was thinking more pointers outside the function and the red flags went up. It would be undesirable in my case to pass that pointer in for every function of the objects because these functions will be called with high frequency and constantly passing in all the those references would be a pain. I need to have all derived entity objects to be able to access the one system object from anywhere at any time. unless you meant to have something like a unique_ptr<System> * within each object. That would act more like a weak_ptr i think.

Comment: @FatalCatharsis: It's just a suggestion; personally, I find explicit dependencies easier to deal with than globals, and I find it quite rare to actually need something from anywhere at any time. But others do balk at the idea of passing references all over the place, and I can understand that. From the name of the class I guess you're using the [God Object anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object), in which case you probably do need access from everywhere.

Comment: Wow, i feel that that describes my situation very well. I also find it disheartening that it's considered an anti-pattern :( . I coded it this way so i could separate two portions of the work. One describes the underlying mechanics and work, and the other is the topside, where you as user would create objects at your whim, utilizing the system object to do your bidding. the entities can be thought of as an almost script at that point. I wouldn't want to consider it an anti-patter though, because i built the system-object very abstractly, where whole objects within the

Comment: system derive from an interface and can be derived from and implemented entirely differently. i would like to think that that covers the maintainenance portion the wiki talks about.